# Removing values from a dictionary using loop

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have `procedure` where I want to remove values from a dictionary based on a certain condition(comparing the key values to another dictionary)

In the `foreach loop` I am however not allowed to modify the dictionary.

Is there perhaps a better way of doing this?

The key values are string,

```
foreach (var archive in dictArchivedTitles)
{
       foreach (var kvp in dictAllTheFiles)
       {
           if (kvp.Key == archive.Key)
           {
               dictAllTheFiles.Remove(kvp.Key);
           }
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following.

```
foreach (var archive in dictArchivedTitles)
{
    if(dictAllTheFiles.ContainsKey(archive.Key)
        dictAllTheFiles.Remove(archive.Key);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just `Remove` and ignore the returned `bool` that indicates success? `dictArchivesTitles.ForAll(archive => dictAllTheFiles.Remove(archive.Key))`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
foreach (var kvp in dictAllTheFiles)
```

to

```
foreach (var kvp in dictAllTheFiles.ToList())
```

That way you would work on a copy of `dictAllTheFiles`

Answer (score 3):

If removing the key of already archived titles is all you want in these nested loops, this would be more efficient and readable (imho):

```
dictAllTheFiles = dictAllTheFiles.Keys.Except(dictArchivedTitles.Keys)
    .ToDictionary(key => key);
```

Note that you need to addd `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to modify either dictionary and have access to LINQ, you could do this:

```
var nonMatchingEntries = 
    dictAllTheFiles.Where(kv => !dictArchivedTitles.ContainsKey(kv.Key));
```